# delete record from dynamodb using boto3 when sort key is not known

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

I have to delete record using PK and SK but I don't know SK whole value for example

on insertion

```
SK = 'VR#'+current_time
```

and `PK = 'AC#'+ID`

so NOW I want to delete a item and doing this

```
def delete_record(key):
    try:
        table = get_dynamodb_table()
        response = table.delete_item(
            Key={
                 "PK" : 'AC#12131',
                 "SK" : 'VR#'
         }      
        )
    except Exception as err:
        print(err)
        return False
    else:
        return response
```

Now I am getting 200 from dynamo but item is not being deleted ..

Comment: Do you have multiple items with pk=`AC#12131` and sk beginning `VR#`? If so, how will you know which to delete?

Comment: @jarmod  pk is unique . if I don't pass sk I mean getting some error saying   `DynamoDB - Key element does not match the schema`

Comment: The point is that a query for `pk=AC#12131` and sk beginning with `VR#` may theoretically return multiple items. Do you know for sure that in your case there will be only one item matching this query? Or that you will know in advance which of the returned items to delete e.g. the one with the earliest current_time suffix?

Answer (score 2):

You’re getting a 200 because it did what you asked, which is to make sure that item doesn’t exist. It’s not an error to delete what doesn’t exist.

You cannot delete an item without specifying its primary key, which is the combo of PK and SK both.

What you can do is a `Query` to fetch the primary key (provide the PK and learn the SK) then you can issue the delete.

Comment: is this right way I am doing ? like in db  VR#11223.

Comment: Sorry, not sure what you’re asking.